# iterate through powerquery to create new table

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have some data in Excel in a powerquery.
I would like to
a) Filter the data (restrict the query to eg client = "xyz") preferably at the source (to avoid network traffic etc, although the source is access so may not delegate the operation.

b) Create subtotal of a column eg by client , project, User.

c) If the above doesn't allow me to do what I want, how can I create a new table based on my manipulation of the power query.

so run the powerquery filtered by client.
write out the lines manually, allowing me full control over formatting / conditional / subtotals.

I have a programming background but I am not familiar with M.
I have data, and wish to subtotal it, and put the subtotal at the top.
Most of my efforts to subtotal have ended up losing the extra columns in the data.

I would otherwise do this by looping through every line in the powerquery in VBA writing manually to a new sheet / table, but think that might not be the ideal solution.

I would also value a good learning resource on M.  book / online.

I probably can work out a way of doing it, but would like to know how I 'should' do it.
I have managed to add / replace columns in the powerquery successfully, but now need to do other things on it.

If I can do code to do this for 1 client, I can then expand by iterating through the clients to produce each sheet.
Thanks.

***edit:** chat gpt suggests:*

```
    Dim query As Object
    Dim row As Range
    
    'Set the query object to the dynamic query
    Set query = PowerQuery.CurrentQuery
    
    'Loop through each row in the query
    For Each row In query.Result.DataBodyRange.Rows
        'Your code here
    Next row
```

Is this the correct approach to the loop through?

Comment: Have you found `ChatGPT` useful? It seems it doesn't even know that `PowerQuery` is not a VBA object and that code cannot possibly run. But you can use the `Table.Group` function to generate your subtotals. If you need more assistance, I suggest you rewrite your question  after reading the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. `Reference` your original query - this will create a new query. Rename it to something sensible
2. Use `Transform`, `Group By` and pick your column e.g. Client. If you want to group by more columns click the `Advanced` radio button
3. Use `Home`, `Merge Queries` to Join back to your original query
4. Expand the resulting `Table` column selecting the columns you require

Hopefully that will be enough to show you how to get back the "missing" columns

Learning materials - I basically google everything - I very often end up in YouTube which is not my preferred medium, but I find the stuff in Microsoft Learn to only be useful once I know what I'm doing - i.e. great reference but not so good as a tutorial